# JavaScript apply giving strange output for String prototype calls

Tags: javascript, oop

When calling `String.prototype` functions with an array of arguments, I am getting unexpected behavior.

```
'foo'.concat.apply(this, ['bar','faz']);
//actual=> [object global]barfaz
//expected=> foobarfaz

'foo'.repeat.apply(this, [3]);
//actual=> [object global][object global][object global]
//expected=> foofoofoo
```

I am only receiving these issues for prototype function calls which have arguments that I am calling `apply` with:

```
'FOO'.toLowerCase();
//actual & expected=> foo
```

I have tried to manually pass in the parameters without `apply`, but in my final code I need to `apply` an array to the parameters, so there seems to be no way around `apply`.

Comment: `'foo'.concat.apply(this.value, ['bar','faz']);` and `'foo'.repeat.apply(this.value, [3]);`

Comment: @JimishGamit `this.value` would resolve to `global.value` in this case I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that `this` is resolve when called, not when it's accessed inside the method. In this case, `this` is resolving to the `global` object. Also, the object these methods are called on become irrelevant, because the first argument to `apply` sets the `this` value in the method.

Instead pass the string as the first argument.

```
String.prototype.concat.apply('foo', ['bar','faz']);

String.prototype.repeat.apply('foo', [3]);
```

Alternate way of doing this:

```
''.concat.apply('foo', ['bar','faz']);

''.repeat.apply('foo', [3]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why so complicated?

```
var a = "foo", b = ["bar", "baz"];
a + b.join("");
```

or as a function

```
//a utility
function string(v){ return v == null? "": String(v) };

function stringconcat(a,b){
  return (Array.isArray(a)? a.join(""): string(a))+
    (Array.isArray(b)? b.join(""): string(b))
}
```

Comment: This does not reflect the type of flexibility I need when calling `.apply()`. From the original article: "but in my final code I need to apply an array to the parameters"